# android Reading image into byte array and last byte of image

Tags: android, image, eof

Android:

I have two byte arrays one byte array of bitmap and another byte array of String.
I have combine these two byte arrays into 3rd one.

I will write 3rd byte array into storage.

When i read that image which is created from combine byte array of image and string i want to know in byte[] that where image bytes ends and where string bytes gets start.

How do i know the byte representation of end of image byte ? or starting of string byte ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you write out the byte array, you should write out the length of the image part. That way you'll know how much data to read. So your file will look like this:

- Length of image (4 bytes, probably - use `DataOutputStream` for simplicity)
- Image data
- Text data

(As an aside, I suggest you explicitly write out the text data as UTF-8, and read it as UTF-8. Or you could just use `DataOutputStream.writeUTF` and `DataInputStream.readUTF` of course...)

Comment: First four bytes i have dedicated for int which holds length of the image but when i try to write on disk due to first four bytes NULL pointer exception

I am calling this method to insert image MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

Comment: @Faisalkhan: Well presumably you have a null reference somewhere, but it's hard to tell just from that. You should possibly start a new question with all the relevant code.